# Empezando en Apps Script, quien me ayuda a mi primer código?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy empezando con Google Apps Script y necesito de vuestra ayuda.

Imagino que para el que está acostumbrado a programar, la ayuda que formulo será de lo más fácil, pero créanme que llevo dándole vueltas 2 ó 3 días y no tengo forma.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es lo siguiente:

- En una hoja de cáculo Spreadsheet con 3 hojas ( hoja 1, hoja2 y base de datos ), quiero que tanto la hoja 1 como la hoja 2 sea para meter datos y una vez que doy al botón guardar ( previamente creado y asignándole el nombre del script ) me lo almacene en la hoja de "base de datos" y me cree una fila nueva para que se almacenen todas las entradas.

Si comparto esta hoja de cálculo con mi compañera, que en esa "base de datos" se almacenen tanto las entradas de ella como las mías.

Adjunto imagen para que se vea más claro.

[image: explicación]

Comment: Bienvenido. No está clara la pregunta para este sitio. Aquí las preguntas además de indicar lo que se espera que haga el código se debe indicar una pregunta específica de programación y mejor aún si se indica una breve descripción de lo que se intentado, buscado e investigado. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

No me queda claro el porque quieres usar una hoja de calculo para almacenar información con un Script y que la información se quede guardada en una hoja compartida con tu compañera, y que los dos puedan hacer lo mismo, al mismo tiempo, y en las mismas hojas, ya que es contradictorio que quieran modificar las mismas celdas al mismo tiempo, esto provoca conflictos de datos y mezcla de información.
Entiendo que quieras iniciar en el maravilloso mundo del Scritp, pero para tu proyecto, te recomiendo una solución mas viable: Un Formulario de Hoja de calculo
https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/